# Is there anyway to get someone out of "attack on sight" mode once diplomacy failed too much?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

I am in the first town, most people seem to like me, but this one lady called Teleri Helvi I failed too much on admire/intimidate. She's following me around town, punching me. If I kill her, I go to jail. If I go rest she's waiting outside. What can I do? I thought if someone hits me first I'm allowed to attack back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to wait until she actually *hurts* you. Since she's punching, that first only downs your stamina - run around a bit and then confront her, wait until you health decreases and then you can finish her. She is an [unimportant character](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Teleri_Helvi#Teleri_Helvi), but personally I'd avoid killing anyone unnecessarily...

Of course, there are better solutions - get the spell [Calm Humanoids](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Illusion_Spells#Calm_Humanoid) or the [Scroll of Tevil's Peace](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Scrolls#Calm) to calm her down. That should give you enough time to talk to her again and bribe her into a more peaceful mood.

Finally, you can also [cheat](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Tes3Mod:Categorical_Function_List). Open the console, click on Helvi, and type

```
setfight 0
stopcombat
```